# Is a NAPP membership valuable to a hobbyist photographer?

Tags: lightroom, photoshop

The [National Association of Photoshop Professionals](http://www.photoshopuser.com/) attracted my information recently. It seems a subscription provides access to the Photoshop User magazine, member-only forums and help, tutorials, and NAPP-exclusive discounts for hardware and software. There seems to Lightroom-oriented features in particular.

Are any P.SE members NAPP subscribers? Would you consider the subscription worthwhile for a hobbyist photographer and artist?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A NAPP membership provides access to quite a few resources, most of which you've listed above.  You'll also get a discount to the Photoshop World conference which is held each year in both Orlando and Las Vegas.  Originally covering Photoshop, as you note the reach of the organization has now extended to Adobe's other primary tool for photographers, Lightroom.

It's definitely a useful organization although I'd argue the value has diminished over time as other excellent online resources including blogs, forums, and even this site have made it easier than ever to learn about and get help with Photoshop and Lightroom.

Is it worth it?  That's a subjective question but I'd say if you're going to drop $300 on Lightroom and 2-3x that amount on Photoshop, spending $99 for the NAPP membership (at least for the first year) is probably a worthwhile investment in education.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think I will subscribe, if for nothing else than the resources available. Fortunately I can get the student discount, a slim one but better than none!